# How to append string in jQuery without quotes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say we have a paragraph:

```
<p>txt0</p>
```

... and we want to append some text:

```
$("p").append("_txt1");
$("p").append("_txt2");
$("p").append("_txt3");
```

The result will be, as expected:

```
txt0_txt1_txt2_txt3
```

However if we inspect the result in browser, what it really is:

```
<p>
   "txt0"
   "_txt1"
   "_txt2"
   "_txt3"
</p>
```

There are 4 different strings that are only rendered as one. The problem is I'm creating a flash object dynamically and appending strings this way will not work because of the quotes. I really need it to be one continuous string like this:

```
<p>
   txt0_txt1_txt2_txt3
</p>
```

Is there a way to append in such a way? Or to remove all the quotes afterwards?

PS. before you say to make one big string before appending, that won't work because the string is too big and for ex. it works in Chrome but not in Firefox or IExplorer (but that's a different issue).

Comment: The quotes are only in the inspector, aren't they? PS: what is a "big string"? I'm sure it fails not because of size, but the wrong syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text`, otherwise you're appending a new TextNode everytime:

```
var $p = $('p');
$p.text('txt0');
$p.text($p.text() + '_txt1');
```

Or with `textContent` it's less confusing:

```
var p = $('p')[0];
p.textContent += 'txt0';
p.textContent += '_txt1';
...
```

Comment: Wouldn't: `$p.text(function(i,oldText) { return oldText + '_txt1'; });` be slightly easier, and a little cheaper? Even if only to avoid calling `text()` twice for each call...

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the html inside the p-tag this way:

```
$('p').html($('p').html() + '_text');
```

Comment: You realise that `html()` will destroy and recreate the HTML each time? So any event-handling/binding is removed? And why use `html()` when `text()` is sufficient? Also: `$('p').html(function(index, oldHTML) { return oldHTML + '_text';});` does precisely the same and doesn't call the `html()` method twice.

Comment: I suggested `html()` because this method is slightly faster than the `text()`-method since the `text()`-method escapes the provided string and `html()`does not. But you are right, if any elements inside the p-tag are binded to event-listeners, `text()` should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is similar to #DonnyDee's

```
$("p").append("_txt1");
$("p").append("_txt2");
$("p").append("_txt3");
$("p").html($("p").html());
```

Somehow .html knows how to remove the quotation marks where there are two strings together i.e. "txt0"
"_txt1" etc

afaik .text() is destructive, i.e. will replace html with text which is perhaps not what we want, although I agree for this example it would suffice.

`$('p').html(function(index, oldHTML) { return oldHTML + '_text';});`

looks like a good solution though. e.g.

```
$("p").append("_txt1");
$("p").append("_txt2");
$("p").append("_txt3");
$("p").html(function(index, oldHTML) { return oldHTML);
```